# Клавиатуры в боте на aiogram

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

В начале есть такая клавиатура

```
menu = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True, row_width=2)
show_all_btn = KeyboardButton('Все задачи')
clear_btn = KeyboardButton('Очистить список')
history_btn = KeyboardButton('История')
menu.add(show_all_btn, clear_btn).add(history_btn)
```

После нажатия на `history_btn` нужно изменить эту клавиатуру на другую и отправить inline клавиатуру, но так чтобы не было лишних сообщений.

```
menu2 = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True, row_width=2)
clear_btn = KeyboardButton('Очистить список')
back_btn= KeyboardButton('Назад')
menu2.add(clear_btn).add(back_btn)
```

Какие способы есть чтобы этого добиться?

Answer (score 0):

**Никак**, ведь `markup` всегда идёт ответом на какоето сообщение и даже если его моментально удалять, то `markup` тоже сразу пропадёт. Вы можете убидиться в этом почитав документацию aiogram, либо же просто даже посмотрев на название класса) **ReplyKeyboardMarkup**, *reply - ответ*

Answer (score 0):

ReplyKeyboardMarkup отправляет сообщение. Вы можете моментально удалить сообщение от пользователя и бота, после чего прислать сообщение с Inline клавиатурой.

Answer (score 0):

Я пришёл к выводу что лучше всё организовать через inline кнопки. Спасибо всем за потраченное время

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).